# jquery delaying process based on response

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, animation

Code below works but what doesn't work properly is delaying process because I don't know how long it is going to take for **process.php** to response. It always differ. No certain time.

Code below works (apart from faulty delay) like this:

1. When I click **run** icon, run icon should disappear and **loader** icon should appear slowly.
2. After response coming from **process.php**, **loader** icon should disappear slowly and **success/fail** icon appear slowly. Straight after **next** (*div*) should appear slowly if *successful*.

Thanks

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
   $("#run").click(function(event)
   {
      $('#run').hide();
      $('#loader').fadeIn(1000).delay(1000);

      $.ajax(
      {
         type       : 'POST',
         url        : 'process.php',
         data       : 'user=jolly',
         dataType   : 'json',
         success    : function(response)
         {
            if(response.status == 'success')
            {
               $('#loader').delay(1000).fadeOut();
               $('#success').delay(4000).fadeIn(1000);
               $('#next').delay(4500).fadeIn(1000);
            }
            else
            {
               $('#loader').delay(1000).fadeOut();
               $('#fail').delay(4000).fadeIn(1000);
               $('#next').delay(4500).fadeIn(1000);
            }
         }
      });
   });
});


<div id="first">
   <img id="run" src="run.png" />
   <img id="loader" src="loader.png" style="display:none;" />
   <img id="success" src="success.png" style="display:none;" />
   <img id="fail" src="fail.png" style="display:none;" />
</div>
<div id="next" style="display:none;">
   ....
   ....
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does it accord with your question?

```
$('#run').hide();
$('#loader').fadeIn(1000);

$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: 'process.php',
  data: 'user=jolly',
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function (response) {
    $('#loader').stop(true).fadeOut(function () {
      if (response.status == 'success') {
        $('#success').fadeIn(1000, function () {
          $('#next').fadeIn(1000);
        });
      } else {
        $('#fail').fadeIn(1000);
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You're doing it wrong? This is not what `delay()` was intended for, you have callbacks to handle this behavior:

```
$(function() {
    $("#run").on('click', function() {
        $(this).hide();
        $('#loader').fadeIn(1000);

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'process.php',
            data: {user: 'jolly'},
            dataType: 'json'
        }).done(function(data) {
            $('#loader').fadeOut(1000, function() {
                $('#success').fadeIn(1000, function() {
                    $('#next').fadeIn(1000);
                });
            });
        }).fail(function() {
            $('#loader').fadeOut(1000, function() {
                $('#success').fadeIn(1000, function() {
                    $('#fail').fadeIn(1000);
                });
            });
        });
    });
});​
```

Also, there's no need to check the `response.status`, jQuery has callbacks available for both.

You could also place the Ajax function in the callback of the initial fadeIn of the loader, but all you're really doing is delaying the data from being showed to the user, and that's **always** a bad thing.

Comment: I take this example on board for future references. Thanks.

Comment: Do you mind if I ask why `done/fail` against `success:function(response)/fail:function(response)` ?

Comment: Actually, that would be `error:function(response)`, but `done()`, `fail()` and `always()` is the new unified way of dealing with ajax callbacks, deferred objects etc.